# Halacha Sefer Quoting Reason for Holocaust

Tags: synagogue, holocaust-shoah

A while ago I saw in a Shailos u'Teshuvos sefer (I think Divrei Yatziv or Be'er Moshe) saying that the Posek saw a woman crying out that this tragedy was happening to Klal Yisroel because of talking in shul, then she disappeared. Where is this teshuvah?

Comment: The response that prompted closure of this question does not show which teshuva sefer this was written in. The response quotes a story without saying where it is published. (?)